# how to get browser full url of the page in nodejs express in environment, seems nginx issue?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using a url rewriting functionality in my application(SparatcusV3.4).
I am calling my backend from node js to check a productcode exists or not
for that I need the current browser url entered by user in the address bar.

I am accessing the url using below code

```
const fullUrl =  req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
```

this is working fine on my local system but when deployed on any environment(by SAP)
this URL is coming as **"127.0.0.1:4200"** , what might be the problem here with environment ?

or what is the correct way to get the full browser url entered by the user ?

any help would be appreciated!!!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const obj = {};
  const rc = request.headers.cookie;
  rc?.split(';')?.forEach((cookie: any) => {
     const parts = cookie?.split('=');
     obj[parts.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(parts?.join('='));
  });

  return obj;
```

it can give list of all cookies in request object so with OBJ['RT'] can give the value and further splitting with '=' we cna get the exact request URL there from we can extract the host and the origin uding below code

```
const cookieName = 'RT';
  const cookieObj = this.getCookieasObject(req);
  let fullURL = cookieObj[cookieName];
  if (fullURL) {
     fullURL = decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse(fullURL).split('=')[1]);
  }

 const url = new URL(fullURL);
  const baseUrl = `${url.protocol}//${url.hostname}`;
```

Comment: I recommend https://stackoverflow.com/a/69066282/11734692 more. Especially if your SSR pod is hidden behind a reverse proxy, it's best to rely on Spartacus tokens `SERVER_REQUEST_URL` and `SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN`. Their Spartacus implementation takes into account the original hostname requested by the end user, but not hostname requested by the direct reverse proxy (likely looking like `localhost:4200`) . See source code: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/4bc9138a6ebf0a91cdd7bfc1ab9b26f9e226bc3c/core-libs/setup/ssr/util/request-origin.ts#L9-L26

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this part of Spartacus docs: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-coding-guidelines/#getting-the-request-url-and-origin

It suggests to use `SERVER_REQUEST_URL` and `SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN` injection tokens when using the setup that's running SSR behind a proxy in order to resolve URLs.

To use these *optional* tokens:

- it is assumed you're using Spartacus' `NgExpressEngineDecorator` from `@spartacus/setup/ssr` in your `server.ts` file.
- when injecting them, you should mark them as `@Optional` (per docs), as these are not available in CSR application.

Comment: actually I need the full url outside of the Spartacus, at nodejs application. which is hosted at SAP env with nginx, so due to nginx we are not able to get host and origin of the request